# sql: compare 2 strings without considering accents and other stuff îăţş = iats (<-should be equal)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to compare 2 strings in sql so that the word

```
"iast" would be equal to "îăşţ"
```

anybody knows how to do this ?

Comment: declare @a1 nvarchar(4)
set @a1 = 'iast'

declare @a2 nvarchar(4)
set @a2 = 'îăşţ'

if @a1 = @a2
  select 1
else 
  select 2

what does it show to you? :)

Comment: in your case there are no problems. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use an accent-insensitive collation for your comparisons:

```
IF 'iast'='îăşţ' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
PRINT 'YES'
```

For more info go through [this link](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3302341/SQL-Server-and-Collation.htm)

Answer (score 3):

```
  select 1 from Table_1
  where 'iast' = 'îăşţ' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
```